# Efficient way to make thousands of curl requests

Tags: perl, curl, cookies

I am using CURL to make thousands of requests. In my code I set the cookie to a specific value and then read in the value on the page. Here is my **Perl** code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $site = "http://SITENAME/?id=";
my $cookie_name = "cookienum123";
print $fh "#\t\tValue\n";
for my $i ('1'..'10000') {
    my $output = `curl -s -H "Cookie: $cookie_name=$i" -L $site$i | grep -Eo "[0-9]+"`;
    print "$i\t\t$output\n";
}
```

So from 1 to 10000, I am setting cookienum123 to that value and reading in the whole response from the page. Then I use grep to just extract the #. The code I have now works fine but I am wondering if there is a faster or more efficient way I can do this.

Please note this does not have to be done as a Perl script (I can also use Windows batch file, Unix shell script, etc).

Edit Jan 18: Added bounty with the note "The desired answer should include a way in Perl to run through several thousand curl requests simultaneously but it needs to be run faster than the rate it is currently running at. It has to write the output to a single file in the end but the order does not matter." Some of the below comments mention *fork* but I am not sure how to apply it to my code. I am very new to Perl as this is my first program in it.

Comment: What about forking to multiple children, say maybe 20 at a time to start, so you can run multiples at once?

Comment: Net::Curl::Multi allows you to make parallel requests to the curl library. Of course,  there's also Parallel::ForkManager to ruin multiple `curl` processes

Comment: @TheJester1977 how would I fork to multiple children?

Comment: @ikegami would that work if these are all writing to the same file?

Comment: @Bijan, check this out for a whimsically produced, yet spot-on accurate description of fork: [link]http://users.telenet.be/bartl/classicperl/fork/all.html

Comment: Would you be able to create an example of this using my example? I still have not found anything of how to create multiple curl forks.

Comment: @ikegami you have some interesting typo there? `:)`

Comment: @Bijan, No, not using `curl`, since you would make sure that only one `curl` runs at a time. If you used Net::Curl::Multi, you would only have to the lock the file when you're writing to it, so that could work, but the output would be in random order. As such, you want to keep the output in memory, in a database or in separate files, then reassemble the output at the end.

Comment: Random output is fine because it goes into excel and I sort the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is an embarrassingly parallel problem. These are great for parallelising, because there's no inter-thread dependency or communication needed.

There's two key ways of doing this in perl - threading or forking. I would *generally* suggest thread based parallel processing for the kind of thing you're doing. This is a matter of choice, but I think it's better suited for collating information.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $numthreads = 20;

my $site        = "http://SITENAME/?id=";
my $cookie_name = "cookienum123";

my $fetch_q   = Thread::Queue->new();
my $collate_q = Thread::Queue->new();


#fetch sub sits in a loop, takes items off 'fetch_q' and runs curl. 
sub fetch {
    while ( my $target = $fetch_q->dequeue() ) {
        my $output =
            `curl -s -H "Cookie: $cookie_name=$target" -L $site$target | grep -Eo "[0-9]+"`;
        $collate_q->enqueue($output);
    }
}

#one instance of collate, which exists to serialise the output from fetch. 
#writing files concurrently can get very messy and build in race conditions. 
sub collate {
    open( my $output_fh, ">", "results.txt" ) or die $!;
    print {$output_fh} "#\t\tValue\n";

    while ( my $result = $collate_q->dequeue() ) {
        print {$output_fh} $result;
    }
    close($output_fh);
}


## main bit:

#start worker threads
my @workers = map { threads->create( \&fetch ) } 1 .. $numthreads;

#collates results. 
my $collater = threads->create( \&collate );

$fetch_q->enqueue( '1' .. '10000' );
$fetch_q->end();

foreach my $thr (@workers) {
    $thr->join();
}

#end collate_q here, because we know all the fetchers are 
#joined - so no more results will be generated. 
#queue will then generate 'undef' when it's empty, and the thread will exit. 
$collate_q->end;

#join will block until thread has exited, e.g. all results in the queue
#have been 'processed'. 
$collater->join;
```

This will spawn 20 worker threads, that'll run in parallel, and collect results as they exit to a file. As an alternative, you could do something similar with `Parallel::ForkManager`, but for data-oriented tasks, I personally prefer threading.

You can use the 'collate' sub to postprocess any data, such as sorting it, counting it, whatever.

I would also point out - using `curl` and `grep` as system calls isn't ideal - I've left them as is, but would suggest looking at `LWP` and allowing perl to handle the text processing, because it's pretty good at it.

Comment: One small thing, you only output $result to the file. How would you output $target to be on the same line?

Comment: enqueue whatever you'd like printed from the source thread. `$collate_queue -> enqueue ( "Target: $target Output $output\n" );` for example.

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to use `Term::ProgressBar` to keep track of how much of the progress has been completed? I have done this before with my previous example but i imagine its different since I am using threads

Comment: `$fetch_q->pending()` will give you a count of items that haven't yet been processed.  You can probably use that, either in a separate thread or the collater thread.

Comment: Perfect, got that working. What would you suggest for # of threads? I found that too little threads is slow but too many (~100) is also a little slow. Is there a reason you chose 20?

Comment: General experience that 20 is usually a good number. Each thread will increase the memory usage. Too many will also start to contend with each other. For a CPU oriented task, I would say one thread per core. For network IO oriented, it very much depends on your infrastructure and request size. It isn't too hard to saturate network pipes this way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the following will do what you want however slamming a server with 10000 simultaneous requests is not very polite.  In fact, harvesting a site's data by walking the id's of a given url doesn't sound very friendly either.  I have NOT tested the following but it should get you 99% of the way there (might be a syntax/usage error somewhere).

See for more info:

- https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook.pod#Non-blocking
- https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent#build_tx
- https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM

Good luck!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::IOLoop;

my $site = 'http://SITENAME/?id=';
my $cookie_name = 'cookienum123';

#open filehandle and write file header
open my $output_fh, q{>}, 'results.txt'
    or die $!;
print {$output_fh} "#\t\tValue\n";


# Use Mojo::UserAgent for concurrent non-blocking requests
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;


#create your requests
for my $i (1..10000) {

    #build transaction
    my $tx = $ua->build_tx(GET => "$site$i");

    #add cookie header
    $tx->req->cookies({name => $cookie_name, value => $i});

    #start "GET" with callback to write to file
    $tx = $ua->start( $tx => sub {
      my ($ua, $mojo) = @_;
      print {$output_fh} $i . "\t\t" . $mojo->res->dom->to_string;
    });
}

# Start event loop if necessary
Mojo::IOLoop->start unless Mojo::IOLoop->is_running;


#close filehandle
close $output_fh;
```